# Access data in custom component in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, components

I am new to Flex so pardon me if my questions are quite basic. I have searched a lot before posting here, might be I was not looking in the right direction. Please redirect me to the path that leads to the solution of the problem. I really appreciate any help that I can get.

I'm following this video tutorial. (I was creating Mobile Project not a simple Flex project like in video)

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=100

All was going fine, until the tutor wanted to add custom component in the application. He added the HBox which I couldn't find in Flash Builder  4.6 so I added HGroup instead in my new component. Now when I want to use the data that was fetched in the parent component in custom component it gives me error. Here is the code and their file names.

File: SearchHomeView.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"    
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Twitter Search">    
    <fx:Declarations>    
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->    
        <s:HTTPService result="onResult(event)" id="service" url="http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=adobe">

        </s:HTTPService>    
    </fx:Declarations>    
    <fx:Script>    
        <![CDATA[    
            import flash.utils.flash_proxy;                       
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;    
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;         

            [Bindable]

            private var ac:ArrayCollection;                       
            private function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void    
            {    
                ac = event.result.feed.entry as ArrayCollection;    
                trace(data);    
                trace(ac);    
            }

            private function doSearch(event:MouseEvent):void    
            {    
                //service.url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=" + tearch.text;    
                service.url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=adobe";    
                service.send();    
            }    
        ]]>    
    </fx:Script>

    <s:TextInput x="25" y="26" width="146" id="tearch"/>    
    <s:Button x="224" y="26" height="33" label="Search" click="doSearch(event)" />    
    <s:List dataProvider="{ac}" itemRenderer="tweet" x="25" y="92" width="274" height="278"></s:List>    
</s:View>
```

File: tweet.mxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        
    <s:HGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"        
              xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="400" height="300">        
        <fx:Declarations>        
            <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->

        </fx:Declarations>        
        <s:Image width="50" height="50" source="{parentDocument.data.link.getItemAt('1').href}">

        </s:Image>        
        <s:TextBase width="100%" text="">                               
        </s:TextBase>        
    </s:HGroup>
```

When I use source to be `source="{parentDocument.data.link.getItemAt('1').href}` ... it removes the error, but displays nothing on the resulting app.

When I use source to be`source="{data.link[1].href}` ... it gives the error,

Multiple markers at this line:

> -1120: Access of undefined property data.
>   -parentDocument

What needs to be done to use the item renderer right in custom component ? Please tell me the solution to it... I'm stuck on it for quite a few time.

Answer (score 3):

Your component `Tweet.mxml` should extend an [ItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/ItemRenderer.html).

In Flex 3 many components could be used as item renderers, that old (Flex 3) `HBox` component you saw in the video works as an item renderer b/c it has a `data` property.

As part of Flex 4's "pay as you go" approach, the container classes (Group, HGroup, etc) do not support being used directly as item renderers. As a result `HGroup` doesn't have a `data` property.

Try making `Tweet.mxml` look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="400" height="300">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <!-- Typically, the dataProvider of your List is an array of objects of the same
         type. So each item renderer that is on screen has it's data property populated
         with one of these items. You can then craft an MXML document like this that
         uses the properties of your array element. You're going to need to use the
         right expression that finds the image source in the data item. If you really
         want to be rendering the array data.link, pass that data w/an ArrayCollection
         to the list instead ... it's hard to advise here w/out knowing what your data
         looks like. -->
    <s:Image width="50" height="50" source="{data.link.getItemAt('1').href}" />

    <s:StyleableTextField width="100%" text="" />

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

The changes I'm making are:

- extend ItemRenderer
- replace HGroup's layout by using the HorizontalLayout in the renderer
- using the data property of the renderer for the source of the image (use the data property to populate all of the dynamic parts of the renderer (like the text field)
- using a StyleableTextField, optimized text for mobile

Comment: Thanks @Sunil D. That was a wonderful answer. I really appreciate that and it some what solved my problem. Here is the file code now.

Only problem is that it gives me the first result only. However it should display the list of all results. Do I need to use loop?

Comment: [code]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" width="400" height="300">
     
     <fx:Declarations>
      <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
     </fx:Declarations>
     
     <s:layout>
      <s:HorizontalLayout />
     </s:layout>
     
     <s:Image width="50" height="50" source="{data.link.getItemAt('1').href}" />
     <s:TextArea text="{data.title}" />
     
     
    </s:ItemRenderer>
[/code]

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. The problem is with the `source` property of your `Image` component. It's specifically asking for index 1 of an array. I'll edit my answer to see if I can clarify...

Comment: I gave it a stab, but I don't think I helped. Maybe it would help if you give an example of what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

In your onResult event handler - be careful to check that you are in fact assigning all items into the arraycollection - If feed.entry is not explicitly an ArrayCollection you will need to iterate the list (assuming this an xmllist because it looks like an RSS feed)...

So instead:

```
protected function onResult(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    if (!ac) ac = new ArrayCollection();
    for each (var entry:XML in event.result.feed..entry)
    {
        ac.addItem(entry);
    }
}
```

As for the ItemRenderer, you have a couple of different options...

1. ItemRenderer - as suggested by @Sunil, this is the 'base' class of renderers to use in spark based lists.
2. DataGroup - this is similar to a Group where you specify a layout, but it creates "renderers" - anything with a 'data' property using a dataprovider, the key to this one though is there is no virtualization it just creates all of them.
3. It gets more complicated than this when you switch to a DataGrid...